# Delete Duplicate records from large csv file C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, csv

I have created a solution which read a large csv file currently 20-30 mb in size, I have tried to delete the duplicate rows based on certain column values that the user chooses at run time using the usual technique of finding duplicate rows but its so slow that it seems the program is not working at all.

What other technique can be applied to remove duplicate records from a csv file

Here's the code, definitely I am doing something wrong

```
DataTable dtCSV = ReadCsv(file, columns);
//columns is a list of string List column
DataTable dt=RemoveDuplicateRecords(dtCSV, columns);

private DataTable RemoveDuplicateRecords(DataTable dtCSV, List<string> columns)
        {
            DataView dv = dtCSV.DefaultView;
            string RowFilter=string.Empty;

            if(dt==null)
            dt = dv.ToTable().Clone();

            DataRow row = dtCSV.Rows[0];
            foreach (DataRow row in dtCSV.Rows)
            {
                try
                {
                    RowFilter = string.Empty;

                    foreach (string column in columns)
                    {
                        string col = column;
                        RowFilter += "[" + col + "]" + "='" + row[col].ToString().Replace("'","''") + "' and ";
                    }
                    RowFilter = RowFilter.Substring(0, RowFilter.Length - 4);
                    dv.RowFilter = RowFilter;
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    bool result = RowExists(dt, RowFilter);
                    if (!result)
                    {
                        dr.ItemArray = dv.ToTable().Rows[0].ItemArray;
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }
            return dt;
        }
```

Comment: 20-30 MB is too small to result in something very slow if you are doing it correctly, so I assume you are not. Share some code.

Comment: i see you catch exception's how many of those occur they can be a major slowdown!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to do this would be to go through the table, building a `HashSet<string>` that contains the combined column values you're interested in.  If you try to add a string that's already there, then you have a duplicate row.  Something like:

```
HashSet<string> ScannedRecords = new HashSet<string>();

foreach (var row in dtCSV.Rows)
{
    // Build a string that contains the combined column values
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (string col in columns)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("[{0}={1}]", col, row[col].ToString());
    }

    // Try to add the string to the HashSet.
    // If Add returns false, then there is a prior record with the same values 
    if (!ScannedRecords.Add(sb.ToString())
    {
        // This record is a duplicate.
    }
}
```

That should be very fast.

Answer (score 2):

If you've implemented your sorting routine as a couple of nested `for` or `foreach` loops, you could optimise it by sorting the data by the columns you wish to de-duplicate against, and simply compare each row to the last row you looked at.

Posting some code is a sure-fire way to get better answers though, without an idea of how you've implemented it anything you get will just be conjecture.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Wrapping the rows in a class and using Linq?

Linq will give you options to get distinct values etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're currently creating a string-defined filter condition for each and every row and then running that against the entire table - that is going to be slow.

Much better to take a Linq2Objects approach where you read each row in turn into an instance of a class and then use the Linq Distinct operator to select only unique objects (non-uniques will be thrown away).

The code would look something like:

```
from row in inputCSV.rows
select row.Distinct()
```

If you don't know the fields you're CSV file is going to have then you may have to modify this slightly - possibly using an object which reads the CSV cells into a List or Dictionary for each row.

For reading objects from file using Linq, this article by someone-or-other might help - http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84468/linq-to-log-files/

Answer (score 0):

Based on the new code you've included in your question, I'll provide this second answer - I still prefer the first answer, but if you have to use `DataTable` and `DataRows`, then this second answer might help:

```
class DataRowEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataRow>
{
    public bool Equals(DataRow x, DataRow y)
    {
        // perform cell-by-cell comparison here
        return result;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DataRow obj)
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }
}

// ...

var comparer = new DataRowEqualityComparer();
var filteredRows = from row in dtCSV.Rows
                   select row.Distinct(comparer);
```